# Syntax for declaring an initialized dictionary Model Property in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I'm attempting to add a dictionary property in one of my model classes that has a set list of key value pairs. However, I don't know how to declare this with the {get; set;} syntax that signals this is a model property and not a simple field.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Profile
    { 
    //classNameID or ID is interpreted by EF as PK.
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

  //How to declare this property with get, set and initialized key/val pairs?
    public string Dictionary<string, string> ProfileDetails =
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"HighSchool", ""},
            {"UndergraduateSchool", ""},
            {"GraduateSchool", ""},

        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare a property and the you can use constructor to initialize it.

```
public class Profile
{ 

    public Dictionary<string, string> ProfileDetails {get; set;}

    public Profile()
    {
        ProfileDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"HighSchool", ""},
            {"UndergraduateSchool", ""},
            {"GraduateSchool", ""},

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Thank you so much, forgot that everything is a "class" even Models classes!

Answer (score 0):

Declaration:

```
class Profile{
  private Dictionary<string,string> _profileDetails;
  public Dictionary<string,string> ProfileDetails { get { return _profileDetails; } }
  public Profile() { _profileDetails = new Dictionary<string,string>(); }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myProfile = new Profile();
myProfile.ProfileDetails["key2"] = "Something";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ProfileDetails {get; set};
```

//An automatic property syntax. This property will be auto backed by a field of the same type i.e. Dictionary

For initialization use class constructor to add keyValuePairs in it.

```
public Profile()
{
    ProfileDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
        {"key01", "value01"},
        {"key02", "value02"},
        {"key03", "value03"}
    };  //This syntax is called collection initializer.
}
```

In this way you can achieve your target here.